# My question was clear and got put on hold anyway

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[How do I convert this LINQ code from C# to VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45765330/how-do-i-convert-this-linq-code-from-c-sharp-to-vb-net)

The question couldn't be any more clear. See the post title.

I assume the downvotes were because people assumed that Enum.ToString() is sufficient for my needs and that I should have easily discovered it. I edited my question to indicate that I would sometimes need to retrieve a string with only an integer as the input.

Comment: It appears that you've mistaken SO for a code translation service. It isn't. Questions that basically ask *Please rewrite this code from language X to language Y for me* don't fare well. A review of the revision history shows why you collected several of the downvotes and probably a few of the close votes.

Comment: People vote to close code translation questions as unclear? Isn't that a misuse of the close reason?

Comment: @BoltClock I think my answer explains why some users might consider it Unclear. I don't know if it's the *optimal* close reason.

Comment: Pretty sure that "Lacks MCVE" is the standard close reason for code translation. See [Code Translation Tagging](/a/265834/5764553)

Comment: @jpmc26: Yeah, I upvoted it when you first posted it.

Comment: @AndrewMyers: The link you provided says that either *unclear* or *lacks MCVE* are appropriate (paragraph two, just before the block quote), and (with all due respect to Bill the Lizard) are not from an authoritative source. You can't infer that one is the standard when two are suggested by someone who cannot define standards.

Comment: @KenWhite: You're objecting to someone saying to use one of the two recommended options, because 1!=2? That seems a little peculiar. Worse, you're neglecting the facts that Bill was a mod at the time, is still highly-respected, and that his answer got quite a few upvotes, indicating a reasonable level of consensus. Since consensus is the primary Meta mechanism for forming policy (mod posts being a secondary one), this seems, if not actually iron-clad, at least a very reliable reference for standards.

Comment: 'To ensure that our translation works as the original, please forward the functional spec, test spec and test harnesses to us here at SO.... on second thoughts, closing as too broad'.

Comment: What's wrong with closing with **unclear**? The text very much says: *"Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need."* If you ask "how to convert this to VB.NET, the answer is "by writing VB.NET code, or what do you mean?"

Comment: @KenWhite Then what do you say to the numerous open questions on this **Question and Answer** Site that are nothing more than "What is <insert language> equivalent of this code?" Shall I post some of them for you? Let's be honest. The reason my Q was closed wasn't because it was unclear or even because it was a "gimmetehcodez" Q (half of the Q's on this site are effectively that), it's because it didn't interest enough people. SO really needs to use the "too broad" flag correctly or even add a flag for "too esoteric" or something like that.

Answer (score 17):

I don't know if "unclear" is *exactly* the right close reason, but your question suffers from a couple fairly major problems.

#### What have you tried?

There's no indication what you tried and why it didn't work. You might think that's silly for a simple question, but it isn't. Explaining that is more than just proving you did your homework. It gives readers/answerers some context about what you already know, and it gives us clues about what's confusing you or what you misunderstood. StackOverflow is here to help you *obtain knowledge*, and your question as written doesn't have enough information for readers to figure out what knowledge you're missing. You could need anything from an entire book length introduction to VB to a link to one piece of unfamiliar syntax. This makes it difficult to determine what to put into an answer.

Your question here gives the perfect example of what kind of information is missing from the post. If you expect people to think `Enum.ToString` is sufficient, why didn't you explain in the question why it's not? Such an explanation would likely give us a window into how you view the problem. This is all part of giving everyone else context about your problem so they can help you find a good solution.

#### What behavior do you expect?

Additionally, "translate this code," questions are usually missing necessary details. The gap is much narrower between C# and VB.NET, but in general, languages don't provide exactly the same features and APIs as each other. This often means there's not an *exact* translation available (without an inordinate amount of code), and in those cases, it's extremely important for you to provide more than a code dump. You need to explain exactly what the input is and what output you want; in other words, you need to say what the code should *do*. Some particular details are likely to be irrelevant to your particular use case, and these seemingly minor details can often affect what functionality in the other language you use. For example, if you're aggregating over a list, the nearest equivalent functionality in the other language might behave differently for an empty list, so you need to specify what needs to happen in that case or if you don't need to handle it. Without that information, answerers can only guess about your needs.

Comment: *I don't know if "unclear" is exactly the right close reason*. That is a great opening sentence and you've set me up for a great suspense. I'm a bit disappointed your answer doesn't end in some sort of epic climax.

Comment: @jpmc26, thanks. Your first Q highlights some of notable flaws at SO. 1) Biographical details about what I tried are merely clutter for such a simple question. Me stating the obvious ("I don't know LINQ") isn't going to help anyone answer it. 2) I didn't mention Enum.ToString() because I forgot it even existed. If SO is concerned that my Q is an X-Y problem, they can clear that up in the comments and ask I repost the question. No need to falsely pin "unclear" to it.

Comment: @cadsharp You're entitled to your opinion if you insist on it, but the reality is that SO has created the premier source for finding information about programming. They must be doing something right to have succeeded where hundreds or maybe thousands of forums and boards have failed, so maybe you're just wrong.

Comment: @jpmc26, as for your 2nd Q, I stated exactly what the code accomplishes in C# and requested the equivalent in VB.NET. That would imply I expect it to accomplish the same thing in VB.NET. Anyway, since my expectation was obvious, someone who knew LINQ in VB.NET gave me the correct answer almost immediately. Cheers to them for giving an **Answer** to my simple **Question** on this **Question and Answer** site!

Comment: @jpmc26, SO has succeeded because the Q&A format is superior and they were the "first to market" (as we would say in business), not because they execute the Q&A format well. They actually do a pretty bad job and this thread is proof of it. Downvotes, for example, mean little more than "I find your question interesting", not "Is your question clear". Some of the most upvoted Q's are Q's that show no research effort (i.e., How do you undo a commit in Git) or are extremely esoteric and obviously just cult of celebrity (e.g., Skeet's time zone Q).

Comment: I would say the chief problem of SO is that its subjective rules encourage condescension. For example, if a Q is unclear or too broad, the OP should be requested to rewrite it. The current system is "downvote and delete it to make you look at a lazy moron". Sums up why I and many others dislike using this site. My profession is teaching a very specific API to non-programmers. If I treated them **anything** like how SO treats its users, I would have been out of a job ages ago.

Comment: @cadsharp That isn't true. [Yahoo! Answers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_Answers) launched in 2005. [Quora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quora) launched less than a year later in 2009. These are largely graveyards, though. It's largely the moderation that attracted people who know what they're talking about.

Comment: I am referring to programming Q&A web sites.

Comment: @cadsharp Downvotes are not disrespectful. Unpleasant, sure. They say something about the question as written, not something about the author. If you want to use the free help of others, the burden is on you to be pleasant toward them. If you want someone to be unconditionally pleasant toward you, then maybe you should hire someone (like your clients do you). Note, btw, that the delete worked heavily in your favor: you recovered all of the lost reputation.

Comment: @cadsharp On the other hand, it is disrespectful to every single person willing to help you that you couldn't be bothered to attempt to tease out your own problem. Looking over the edit history, the extent of your efforts was to try running it through an *automatic translator* before giving up. You didn't even *try* to write your own code and figure out what was wrong.

Comment: @cadsharp The bottom line is that the question you could and should have asked is, "Why won't my VB.NET code compile?" or "Why does this VB.NET code behave not the way I want it to?" It should be unsurprising to you if others found your question unclear when you weren't even clear on what the actual problem was yourself.

Comment: @cadsharp Also contributing to the confusion is statements that are wrong. You say that the method you wrote takes an enum value or an `int`, but it *always* takes an `int`. Did you not realize that the system would be casting any input into an `int` when you passed it in? That fact offers some *immediate* clues about how you can accomplish what you're trying to do and makes the function you wrote unnecessary. C# and VB.NET are strongly typed. You could just call `ToString()` when you have an enum and cast it when you have an `int`. At most, you need a function to handle "UNKNOWN" for `int`s.

Comment: @cadsharp And having said all that, now I've wasted 30 minutes detailing how confused you are on the technical issue to someone who is utterly ungrateful for the free time I've spent trying to help you. Not to mention the time I originally spent trying to give you advice on improving the question. See the problem now, and why SO values high quality questions and provides moderation around them?

Comment: @cadsharp There is a fundamental difference between a Q&A site and a teacher. I've been both. No, you cannot treat students the way we treat questions here. But students are not questions, and we aren't a tutorial service.